# Change Taxonomy Permalinks

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks

I have custom posts and I created one page that shows all my custom posts.

Example: `www.example.com/archive-page`

I wonder if I can change permalinks of categories and tags related to this custom post.

Now i have:

- `www.example.com/my-custom-post-type-cats/my-category-1`
- `www.example.com/my-custom-post-type-tags/my-tag-1`

And I want something like this:

- `www.example.com/archive-page?category=1`
- `www.example.com/archive-page?tag=1`

If this is possible, can I get new URLs by `get_category_link()` for example?

If not, can i just override default taxonomy URLs to point they to my **archive-page**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If not, can i just override default taxonomy URLs to point they to my archive-page?

I am not sure about newer version of the WP, but In the past I managed to create a taxonomy, say `ivan_taxonomy` and I also created a page, which slug was also `ivan_taxonomy`. So, when user viewed posts through `example.com/ivan_taxonomy/super-cool-post/`, he could have gotten easily to `example.com/ivan_taxonomy/` and my page was being displayed. (Not sure, whether you wanted to know sth like this :-D)

> And I want something like this:
>
> …

Easy, grab a url param and create a WP_Query with dependence on it, for example:

```
if(isset($_GET) && false != $_GET)
{
    //whitelist
    $allowed = array("category", "tag");

    $url_params = array_keys($_GET);

    //get your term, provided it is the first in a query, 
    $term = (string)array_shift($url_params);

    //get your id
    $id = (int)$_GET[$term];

    //validate input
    if(in_array($term, $allowed) && (false != get_the_term_list( $id, $term )))
    {
        $query = new WP_Query(array($term => $id));
    }
```

}

Or it would be a lot easier with url like `example.com/archive-page/?term=category&id=8`.

Comment: The problem is when i have multiple categories and i can't do what you suggest with just one page.

Comment: Something I've got wrong, so, when you have multiple categoies, and you want to display posts from a particular category, you distinguish it with numeric ID from URL, doesn't you?